# Dynamic 301 .htaccess default page

Tags: php, .htaccess, dynamic, content-management-system

I'm using Apache/PHP/MySql as the environment for a CMS, and one of the modules I've written for it allows the user to define any page as the root page for the site. What I would like to do is allow and automate the process of redirecting the page's url such as for example "http://mysite.com/?page=home" to "http://mysite.com/".

I've got the .htaccess hard-coded to look for a common default page name of "home" using this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)page=home$
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
```

But what I'd like to do is make it so the user doesn't have to touch the .htaccess file and it would automatically be updated when a default page is chosen from within the CMS. I'm assuming I could use a comment to start and end the rewrite portion of .htaccess, but at this point I'm kinda lost without a good place to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've come up with a solution. I did have to use PHP. For the solution, check out my code snipt: http://snipt.org/xnYm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

If the query string starts with `page=home` then redirect

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=home$
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
```

I think you would use home as default home page, no matter what home default page is chosen by the user, so make changes into CMS and dont create/edit .htaccess files

Comment: Thank you but the idea is to let the user define ANY page as the default. As web developers WE know best practices, however the audience I'm developing this CMS for doesn't know what we do, and I need to make sure that SEO works for any page if it's defined as the default page.